# Spring bean injection of Integer fails

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, integer

I have defined 4 beans of type java.lang.Integer. 
Two beans are injected properly(gradeSyncMinCount and gradeSyncMaxCount) but I have issue injecting the other 2. These 2 beans that have a problem are the ones I just created. 
Also the same 4 beans can be successfully injected into a controller class. I tried @Qualifier, @Resource, @Autowired. I checked for component scan as well. 
I dont see what I am missing.Please help.

Caused by:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.Integer] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: gradeSyncMaxCount,gradeSyncMinCount
```

My Java class

```
@Autowired
private Integer gradeSyncMinCount;
@Autowired
private Integer gradeSyncMaxCount;
@Autowired
private Integer maxDeliveryAttempt;
@Autowired
private Integer maxDaysToKeep;
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="maxDeliveryAttempt" class="java.lang.Integer">
<constructor-arg value="4" />
</bean>

<bean id="maxDaysToKeep" class="java.lang.Integer">
<constructor-arg value="200" />
</bean>
<bean id="gradeSyncMaxCount" class="java.lang.Integer">
<constructor-arg value="500" />
</bean>  
<bean id="gradeSyncMinCount" class="java.lang.Integer">
<constructor-arg value="15" />
</bean>
```

Comment: This is my applicationContext.xml?!!!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the `@Qualifier` annotation or `autowired=byName`, you have 4 beans of the same type and spring can't which one to inject where. With `@Qualifier` you can pass the name of the bean that you want to inject, ending in something like:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("gradeSyncMinCount")
private Integer gradeSyncMinCount;
```

Hope it helps!